# Sorting Column of Grades K - 12 --- Can I make Excel think "K" is a Zero?

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, excel-formula

I work in education and have a table of student information that we'll sort and filter. One of the columns is for their grade level -- Kindergarten through 12. We often want to sort the information by grade level and obviously the students with "K" in the grade column show up LAST (or "largest"), since it isn't a number.

Is there anything I can do to make Excel think that the letter "K" in this column is a zero?

The work-around I've been using is to just put a "0" instead of a K. Not ideal but it works.

Comment: Have a helper column with the 0-12 and sort on that.

Comment: At that point its not much different than just typing 0 instead of K, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another Option:

use a custom number format of:

```
General;General;"K"
```

Which will allow you to enter `0` in for `K` and the `K` will be visible.

[image]

Then when you sort Excel sees it as `0` not `K`

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Try using Custom Sort:

Current table -

[image]

Click on Grade Filter > Sort by color > Custom Sort...

Sort by "Grade", Order: Custom List...

Now add your custom list: K,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12

Final result -

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Custom Sort in Excel and define the order that you like.

In the filter drop-down, go to **Sort by color** and choose **Custom Sort**. There you can choose the column you want to sort and choose/create a custom sort

**Below is the output of a sorted column**: 
[image: Sample Output]

**Steps to follow**: 
**Step-1:** 
[image: Custom Sort 1]

**Step-2:** 
[image: Custom Sort 2]

**Step-3:** 
[image: Custom Sort 3]